# Tick mark next to file name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone please tell me what this tick mark sign means? I don't know how this appeared, may be I pressed some key combination while working or maybe be I did something wrong. Whatever my code/project is running fine.

But, I want to know what this means, and how I can undo this.

[image: See the sign (Tick mark) before the activity title]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a bookmark. Bookmarks allow you to mark lines of code or entire files as "favourites" for quick access. You can show your existing bookmarks by going to `Naviate -> Bookmarks -> Show Bookmarks` or by using the key shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

To remove a bookmark, highlight the file or line and press <kbd>F11</kbd>, or go to `Navigate -> Bookmarks -> Toggle Bookmark`.